# Re-building list from a list of dictionary

Tags: python

I've been trying to re-build the following list of dict by similar key:

Example:

```
n = [{'service_name': '001', 'service_type':'API', 'db_name': 'abc', 'db_type': 'test'},
     {'service_name': '002', 'service_type':'API', 'db_name': 'def', 'db_type': 'dev'}, 
     {'service_name': '003', 'service_type':'Service', 'db_name': 'ghi', 'db_type': 'uat'}
    ]
```

I want to group them by similar key and the expected output to be:

for service:

```
service: [{'service_name': '001', 'service_type':'API'}, 
          {'service_name': '002', 'service_type':'API'}, 
          {'service_name': '003', 'service_type':'Service'}]
```

for db:

```
db: [{'db_name': 'abc', 'db_type': 'test'},
     {'db_name': 'def', 'db_type': 'dev'}, 
     {'db_name': 'ghi', 'db_type': 'uat'}]
```

Prefix will be generated dynamically. It could be service, db, sch, etc.. I wonder would it be possible to done it through a loop and generate these new keys (service, db, sch.etc) on the fly.

If anyone can shed some lights, that would be very helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suggest that you use a list comprehension.

Comment: "I've been trying..." - what results did you get? What was the problem?

Comment: Hi@mkrieger1, I was also at the point where I can generate the list by hard-coding the key, but just can't get my head around to get all the prefix without putting a nested loop. Looking for more efficient built-in method to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

**for *service***:

```
key = 'service'
[{v:k[v] for v in k if v.startswith(key)} for k in n]
```

**Output:**

```
[{'service_name': '001', 'service_type': 'API'},
 {'service_name': '002', 'service_type': 'API'},
 {'service_name': '003', 'service_type': 'Service'}]
```

**for *db***:

```
key = 'db'
[{v:k[v] for v in k if v.startswith(key)} for k in n]
```

**Output:**

```
[{'db_name': 'abc', 'db_type': 'test'},
 {'db_name': 'def', 'db_type': 'dev'},
 {'db_name': 'ghi', 'db_type': 'uat'}]
```

**Full code with dynamic prefixes :**

```
from itertools import combinations
from os.path import commonprefix

n = [{'service_name': '001', 
      'service_type':'API', 
      'db_name': 'abc', 
      'db_type': 'test'},
     {'service_name': '002', 
      'service_type':'API', 
      'db_name': 'def', 
      'db_type': 'dev'}, 
     {'service_name': '003', 
      'service_type':'Service', 
      'db_name': 'ghi', 
      'db_type': 'uat'}
    ]

prefixes = set()
for dictio in n:
  L = dictio.keys()
  line_prefixes = [commonprefix([i,j]) 
                   for i, j in list(combinations(L, 2)) 
                   if commonprefix([i,j]) != '']
  prefixes.update(line_prefixes)

print(prefixes)

for key in prefixes:
  print([{v:k[v] for v in k if v.startswith(key)} for k in n])
```

**Output:**

```
{'service_', 'db_'}
[{'service_name': '001', 
  'service_type': 'API'}, 
 {'service_name': '002', 
  'service_type': 'API'}, 
 {'service_name': '003', 
  'service_type': 'Service'}]
[{'db_name': 'abc', 
  'db_type': 'test'}, 
 {'db_name': 'def', 
  'db_type': 'dev'}, 
 {'db_name': 'ghi', 
  'db_type': 'uat'}]
```

Comment: leveraging the prefixes is a good trick +1

Comment: Hi @DavidK, I should clarify this a bit. I can't pre-define the prefix by hard coding. prefix will be generated dynamically. Thanks for checking this btw

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks @DavidK, that's exactly what the expected output will be.

Comment: @DavidK new thing I learned today:  commonprefix :)

Comment: That's the goal :)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of fancy one-liners and libraries you can use to help with this, but I'd suggest manually iterating so you gain an understanding of basic collection traversal:

```
n = [{'service_name': '001', 'service_type':'API', 'db_name': 'abc', 'db_type': 'test'},
     {'service_name': '002', 'service_type':'API', 'db_name': 'def', 'db_type': 'dev'}, 
     {'service_name': '003', 'service_type':'Service', 'db_name': 'ghi', 'db_type': 'uat'}
    ]

service = []
db = []

for d in n:
  service.append({"service_name": d["service_name"], "service_type": d["service_type"]})
  db.append({"db_name": d["db_name"], "db_type": d["db_type"]})

from pprint import pprint
pprint(service)
pprint(db)
```